# The resource class for this page was not found. Please check if the resource file exists and try again

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, iis, webforms

```
26/10/2020 11:43:24
Error 500
Message: Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown.
Inner Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: The resource class for this page was not found.  Please check if the resource file exists and try again.
   at System.Web.Compilation.LocalResXResourceProvider.CreateResourceManager()
   at System.Web.Compilation.BaseResXResourceProvider.GetObject(String resourceKey, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Web.Compilation.ResourceExpressionBuilder.GetResourceObject(IResourceProvider resourceProvider, String resourceKey, CultureInfo culture, Type objType, String propName)
   at System.Web.Compilation.ResourceExpressionBuilder.GetResourceObject(IResourceProvider resourceProvider, String resourceKey, CultureInfo culture)
   at pCatalogo.CreaStrumentiSopra()
   at pCatalogo.CreateChildControls()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.EnsureChildControls()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
```

This error occurs randomly, but after recycling the app pool it fixes it.
Also this error occurs only on some online domains, it has never happened to me locally and the software is the same for everyone.
Any idea how to fix?

Comment: I doubt if the case relates to the Network/Route issue. For example, some requests are discarded by the application gateway, which may be caused by the wrong NAT tables configured in the public firewall or router. You could verify this by accessing the website with a local IP.

Comment: are you sure? because the strange thing is that when the error starts multiple resource files start to freeze (both in App_LocalResources and in App_GlobalResources).
The site goes down due to this problem until IIS restart.
The sites are E-commerce hosted on Windows servers.

For example, the Home page may remain viewable, but all catalog and product pages become inaccessible because they cannot locate the corresponding resource file.